# PHP get name for locale

Tags: php, translation, locale, multilingual

I want to get a localized name for a locale.
For example:

I have an array of locales (in real the array is much bigger):

```
$languageAndRegion = array (
    'de',
    'de_AT',
    'de_CH',
    'de_DE',
    'de_LI',
    'de_LU'
);
```

And now i want to get something like that:

```
foreach ($languageAndRegion as &$value) {
    $name = magicFunction($value, 'en');
    echo $name;
}
```

The output should be like that:

```
German
German (Austria)
German (Germany)
German (Swiss)
...
```

Comment: Please make your differents sample of code for the same part. the 1st array contains 6 values (which corresponds to the locale id), and you want the output containing "German", "Austria" and such. There is a lot of thing missing. Maybe all is inside magicFunction ?

Comment: @Asenar i don´t know how to do another example. i just want to get the name of for example 'de_AT'.

Comment: so you want a `magicFunction` which would return `German, (Austria)` when the value = de_AT ?

Comment: @Asenar yes exactly. the function is called locale_get_display_name but it returns nothing. i don´t know how to enable it.

Comment: The documentation is here : http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplayname.php

Comment: @Asenar ah ok so i need PECL intl >= 1.0.0. my php version is ok.
But how to install PECL intl on linux?

Comment: check on the documentation, there is probably an installation chapter. If not, search for "how to install PECL intl "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locale_get_display_name($value, 'en');`?

Comment: this function returns nothing but i don´t know why

Comment: Have you installed the extension? It doesn't come turned on by default for all php setups. Once it is installed, it definitely does what you want.

Comment: Oh ok thats the reason.I didn´t installed any extension. Which do i need to enable?

Comment: I use MacPorts for PHP, so I did ```sudo port install php55-intl```. Depending on your PHP version and setup, your procedure might be different.